# How to get a item from list by comparing properties

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of `GT` and I want to get the item where the `TimeStamp` is biggest then all of items.

```
public class GT
{
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }
    public double TimeStamp { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What have you researched ? Whats the problem you are having, why isn't Linq working for you?

Comment: I tried to use lambda but I need to compare with a value to get the items.
var result = gtList.select(a => a.ActitivtyName).where(a => a.TimeStamp > ??)

Comment: `gtList.select(a => a.ActitivtyName)` is a `IEnumerable<string>` and `string` doesn't have `TimeStamp` property, so your lambda can't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ordering them first, then using [`FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found.

```
var highest = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp)
                     .FirstOrDefault();

if(highest != null)
     Console.WriteLine(highest.ActivityName);
```